# Comma code project from "Automate the Boring Stuff with Python"

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
spam = ['apples','dogs','tofu']

try:
    def comma(items):
        if range(len(items) >= 2):
            for i in range(len(items) - 2):
                print(items[i], end=', ')

            if range(len(items) > 2):
                print(items[-2] + ', and ' + items[-1])
            elif range(len(items) <= 2):
                print(items[-2] + ' and ' + items[-1])

        else:
            print(items[0])


    comma(spam)

except IndexError:
    print('Index Error: please enter a valid list.')
```

Comment: You forgot to describe in plain English what the code _is supposed_ to do.

Comment: I'd suggest including the problem description from https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter4/ in your post to make it clear to readers what your code is trying to do.

Answer (score 3):

**Don't use try-except blocks casually or excessively**. You don't need them in
the current case. And when exception handling is truly needed, you should
restrict its use to the narrowest possible scope -- the specific lines where
the error can occur.

**You code will fail if given an empty list**. Specifically, this line:
`print(items[0])`.

**Whenever feasible, write functions that return data rather than causing side
effects**. Printing is one example of a side effect, and it is better to keep
that kind of behavior separate from the logical complexity of the program. In
the current situation, our primary logic is joining items into a comma-phrase.
That logic should be done in a data-oriented function: take the items as input
and return a string as output. Print elsewhere -- for example, in a `main()`
function that orchestrates the program by subjecting the comma-phrase logic
to various tests.

**Speaking of tests, get in the habit of writing them**. As illustrated below.
Even better would be to learn how to use one of the Python testing frameworks,
such as pytest.

**Breaking down a problem**. It's easy to overcomplicate a problem like this if
you jump too quickly into coding. Step back and analyze the cases as shown in
the table below. If we have 3 or more items, we need to do some comma-joining.
But in all other cases, we can just return an and-joined string.

```text
items           desired output
------------------------------
[]              ''
[A]             'A'
[A, B]          'A and B'
[A, B, C]       'A, B, and C'
[A, B, C, D]    'A, B, C, and D'
```

**Don't forget about list slicing**. For the comma-joining logic, we can grab
all items other than the last one via a slice: `items[0:-1]`.

```
def main():
    # Some test data.
    XS = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
    TESTS = (
        ([], ''),
        (XS[0:1], 'A'),
        (XS[0:2], 'A and B'),
        (XS[0:3], 'A, B, and C'),
        (XS, 'A, B, C, and D'),
    )
    # Exercise our function.
    for items, exp in TESTS:
        got = comma_phrase(items)
        if got == exp:
            print('ok')
        else:
            print(items, (got, exp))

def comma_phrase(items):
    if len(items) < 3:
        return ' and '.join(items)
    else:
        return ', '.join(items[0:-1]) + ', and ' + items[-1]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 2):

```
        if range(len(items) >= 2):
            ...
            if range(len(items) > 2):
                ...
            elif range(len(items) <= 2):
                ...
```

What are you doing here?  This code is very obfuscated, bordering on outright invalid.

```
>>> help(range)
Help on class range in module builtins:

class range(object)
 |  range(stop) -> range object
 |  range(start, stop[, step]) -> range object
 |
 |  Return an object that produces a sequence of integers from start (inclusive)
 |  to stop (exclusive) by step. ...
 |  ...
```

As you can see from the help, `range()` expects between 1 and 3 arguments, which are expected to be integers.  You are passing in the result of boolean expressions, so either `True` or `False`.  In integer context, `True` and `False` evaluate to `1` and `0` respectively.

```
>>> range(True)
range(0, 1)
>>> range(False)
range(0, 0)
```

Now, these `range` object are then used in boolean contexts in the `if` and `elif` conditions.  Non-empty ranges are `True` and empty ranges are `False` ...

```
>>> bool(range(0, 1))
True
>>> bool(range(0, 0))
False
```

... so you've gone full circle `bool(range(True))` evaluates to `True` and `bool(range(False))` evaluates to `False`.  The calls to `range(...)` do nothing for you.  The statements could simple have been:

```
        if len(items) >= 2:
            ...
            if len(items) > 2:
                ...
            elif len(items) <= 2:
                ...
```

Of course, `len()` will always return a nice safe integer value (never `NaN`), so if `len(items) > 2` is not true, then `len(items) <= 2` will be true, and you could use a simple `else` clause.

```
        if len(items) >= 2:
            ...
            if len(items) > 2:
                ...
            else:
                ...
```